# TypeError in sns.jointplot

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, seaborn

I am trying to plot a simple linear fit to a set of data from a pandas dataframe. 
This is my code:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import sklearn
import seaborn as sns
import sys
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df = pd.read_csv("../Machine Learning/housing.data", header=None,
                 delim_whitespace=True)

col_name = ['Crime', 'ZN', 'Indus', 'Chas', 'Nox','RM', 'Age', 'Dis', 
            'Rad', 'Tax', 'PTRatio', 'B', 'LSTAT', 'MEDV']

df.columns = col_name

X = df.RM.values.reshape(-1,1)
y = df.MEDV.values.reshape(-1,1)

from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression

model = LinearRegression()

model.fit(X,y)

plt.figure(figsize=(12,10))
sns.jointplot(x='RM', y='MEDV', data=df, kind='reg', height=10)
plt.show()
```

I am getting the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "regression_scipy.py", line 74, in <module>
    sns.jointplot(x='RM', y='MEDV', data=df, kind='reg', height=10) ...
TypeError: Cannot cast array data from dtype('int64') to dtype('int32') according to the rule 'safe'
```

I checked my arrays X and y. They are `numpy.ndarrays`.

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: Can you include some of the data you are using? Also which version of Python are you using? I'm not able to replicate your error.

Answer (score 0):

The `TypeError` arises because the data frame `df` type is 64-bit `int` where type 32-bit `int` is expected. Downcasting from 64 to 32 bit integer is unsafe - it brings the danger of overflow, hence it is not automatically performed. If you are confident your data can be safely stored as 32 bit integers then one way you should be able to resolve the error is by explicitly casting via the `pandas.DataFrame.astype` method. I.e.

```py
sns.jointplot(x='RM', y='MEDV', data=df.astype('int32'), kind='reg', height=10)
```

Comment: Thanks for the input! However, I tried it, but I am still getting the same error.